# Why is the C++17 tag replaced by the C++1z tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

In my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027922/why-doesnt-this-undefined-extern-variable-result-in-a-linker-error-in-c17), I was trying to add the [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) tag, but when I select the tag and save it, it is replaced by the [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) tag.

Why is the [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) tag replaced by the [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) tag? (That is, why does this synonym exist?)

Comment: [Because it's got a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b1z/synonyms).

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: Are you asking about the mechanics of synonyms, or about the reason for this particular one's creation?

Comment: @NathanTuggy  particular one's.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The C++17 tag is being automatically replaced by the C++1z tag because [the former is a synonym of the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b1z/synonyms). [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) is the "master" tag, so it is the one that gets ultimately displayed.

Why is [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) the "master" tag? For historical reasons, mostly. When the tag was created, we didn't know that the language draft known as C++1z would ultimately be released in 2017, so using the name "C++17" was potentially misleading. We're now pretty sure, and people are starting to use the name "C++17" most of the time, but the synonym mapping hasn't been reversed, and arguably shouldn't be until C++17 is *officially* released later this year.

[Compilers still tend](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) to [call it C++1z, too](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), for the same reasons.

The nice thing about synonyms, of course, is that you don't need to worry about any of these details. You just enter (or search for) [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and the system takes care of it.

Comment: So what's the tag for the _next_ version of C++ going to be? From [this question found randomly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177625/c14-or-c1y) the previous version was `c++1y` but _we've run out of alphabet!_. I vote for `c++1{`.

Comment: @TripeHound It'll probably be [c++2a] or [c++1aa] #MakingShitUp (I like [c++1{] though)

Comment: probably because they are expecting too much to come after ++17 so it's wise to make ascii codification if you don't want to end like with a SSN

Comment: Next one *is* **C++20** according to https://isocpp.org/std/status

Comment: This. C++17 does not exist, no matter how sure everybody is that it _will_ exist soon.

Comment: When the ISO committee *formally* canonizes C++17, and it is published in 2017, then we can (and should) reverse the synonym.