# Rename c++1z tag to c++17

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag made sense pre-official-release of C++17, especially given that historically the standards haven't always come out in the expected year, but [given that C++17 is now officially released](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html), shouldn't we update the tag name?

## Relevant

[Why is the C++17 tag replaced by the C++1z tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352031/why-is-the-c17-tag-replaced-by-the-c1z-tag)

Comment: Can't we simply change the synonym direction such that c++1z points to c++17?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm no tag expert, I just want it to show `c++17`

Comment: @BDL I assume that's what the author of this question is asking (semantics, renaming c++1z to c++17 and adding c++1z to it as a synonym is the same as reversing the synonym direction)

Comment: Last I checked, C++17 has *not* been officially standardized yet. Only a draft standard has been published.

Comment: @CodyGray: According to Herb Sutter, chair of the C++ committee, [C++17  is formally approved](https://herbsutter.com/2017/09/06/c17-is-formally-approved/): "Unanimous approval of a DIS means that we get to skip the FDIS ballot (as we hoped) and proceed directly to publication. As far as ISO is concerned, we are now done and they are just waiting for us to update the document editorially and send them the final PDF we want to be published."

Comment: @CodyGray As Nicol's answer states, C++17 has been published. So can we now flip the tag synonym?

Comment: @CodyGray We even have **[tag:c++20]** instead of **c++2x**!

Comment: @ibug CodeGray hasn't been online since Dec 17.  Dec 17.  C++ 17.  Coincidence?

Answer (score 13):

OK, we are now completely out of excuses for this. [C++17 is officially published,](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html) and it's still 2017. This is as done as it gets.

So can someone who has the power please change the tags already?

---

OK seriously, it's 2018, and the standard was published last year. How many sites do I have to link to in order to prove that C++17 is what it's called?

---

What has to be done to get this to happen? Are there moderators or users who can change tag synonyms like this or does this need to be escalated to SO employees?

Comment: And now it's 2018, and the tags are still not reversed!

Comment: I've removed the synonym for now so that further questions aren't automatically re-mapped to c++1z... Not sure what could be done historically about the c++1z... presumably some of them aren't suitable for c++17 and some are? That's probably another issue.

Comment: @JonClements: I say that it's best to do what we did for C++14/C++1y: reverse the synonym entirely. While there were probably some questions tagged c++1y that weren't appropriate for C++14, the number is probably too few to worry about.

Comment: Seems fair and after reading a few bits consistent. I've done the synonym for 1z to 17 - I haven't done any merging etc... We'll see how it works out...

Comment: @JonClements Dunno what the right procedure is, but I can't [search for my C++1z posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2069064+[c%2b%2b1z])

Comment: @JonClements And the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b17/topusers) page reports 6 total questions.

Comment: @Barry: Maybe this is something that takes time for the server to work out. C++1y doesn't exhibit those problems.

Comment: @JonClements Just wanted to ping a week later - those two things are still true (can't search my C++1z posts and the top users page just has the 39 questions).

Comment: @Barry: The comments to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362225/c17-tag-behaves-oddly-after-synonym-change) help explain the issue. Hopefully, someone will deal with it.

Comment: @JonClements The problem described in Barry's previous comments has not yet been fixed. Nicol has asked another [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362225/241631) about this, which hasn't been addressed either.