# C++17 tag behaves oddly after synonym change

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Once upon a time, there was the [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) tag, which had a synonym [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). [Eventually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357105/rename-c1z-tag-to-c17/360354#comment547858_360354), this was flipped to C++17 being the primary tag, with C++1z as the synonym.

The problem is that this flip didn't seem to take. Or at least, not properly. On the [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) page, you can see that it claims 1.5K questions with the tag, but the [top-users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B17/topusers) only claims questions tagged with the actual [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) tag. That is, those tagged [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) still technically use that tag, even though it is a synonym.

Is this something where we have to go to every question with the [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) and change it manually to [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) (and how would we be able to do that, since we cannot search for c++1z as a tag)? Or is that something that's going to happen automatically at some point?

---

> There's that CM mass edit tool that doesn't bump questions. This seems like a reasonable use case for that tool.

That sounds like a good idea. What does it take to get that moving forward? As I understand it, something similar was done for the C++14/C++1y tag switchover too.

Comment: Can we blame caching?

Comment: @Braiam Blame SE, safer bet

Comment: @Justastudent probably http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type

Comment: There's that CM mass edit tool that doesn't bump questions. This seems like a reasonable use case for that tool.

Comment: Yeah, this is really annoying when I can't even find my own answers by tag.

Comment: Umm.... I was kind of hoping it was just a bad case of caching and it'd resolve itself. I need to read up on a few bits and then I'll see what I can do. It's not helping that the mod tag tools don't appear to have been fixed for tags with symbols when the main tag stuff was...

Comment: @Nicol I've merged them. That should have sorted out the issues - please let me know if there's any more :)